# Sorteio aleatório, mas com diferentes probabilidades

Tags: matemática, números-aleatórios

Estou implementando um sistema onde o usuário clica em um botão e um sorteio com bolas de cores diferentes ocorre, porém para cada cor existe uma probabilidade:

Ele possui 30% de chances de pegar uma bola azul
Ele possui 10% de chances de pegar uma bola vermelha
Ele possui 5% de chances de pegar uma bola dourada
Ele possui 30% de chances de pegar uma bola preta
Ele possui 25% de chances de pegar uma bola cinza

Como fazer este sorteio? Tenho que criar uma lista onde a quantidade de itens represente estas probabilidades e então realizar um sorteio de forma aleatória ou existe um jeito melhor?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Como explicado pelo @ramaral, você divide a porcentagem em faixas proporcionais.

- Os primeiros 30% obviamente são uma bola azul.
- Para saber se é uma vermelha, a lógica é ser maior do que 30, e menor ou igual a 30 + 10 (que é a porcentagem da vermelha).
- Para saber se é uma dourada, aplicamos o mesmo raciocínio: o valor deve ser maior que 30 da azul, somado com os 10 da vermelha, e menor do que 30 + 10 + 5 (que é a porcentagem da dourada)
- sucessivamente aplicamos a mesma lógica.

Em resumo, a faixa de cada cor para um teste lógico é dada pela fórmula

```
    x > (soma dos ítens anteriores)
    &&
    x <= (soma dos itens anteriores + porcentagem da cor atual)
```

(vide tabela na postagem do @ramaral para comparação)

### Visualizando de outra maneira:

Todos são múltiplos de 5, então vamos simplificar, só pra efeitos de visualização:

```
 30 / 5 =  6  azul
 10 / 5 =  2  vermelha
  5 / 5 =  1  dourada 
 30 / 5 =  6  preta
 25 / 5 =  5  cinza
100 / 5 = 20  TOTAL
```

Código genérico, só para visualizar que temos uma proporção de `case`s de acordo com cada porcentagem:

```
x = random( 1, 20 )

switch x
   case 1:
   case 2:
   case 3:
   case 4:
   case 5:
   case 6:
      return "azul"
      exit
   case 7:
   case 8:
      return "vermelha"
      exit
   case 9:
      return "dourada"
      exit
   case 10:
   case 11:
   case 12:
   case 13:
   case 14:
   case 15:
      return "preta"
      exit
   case 16: // podia ser um otherwise, claro
   case 17:
   case 18:
   case 19:
   case 20:
      return "cinza"
      exit
```

### Usando um algoritmo

Se você tivesse a necessidade de reaproveitar código em outras distribuições, seria o caso de fazer um array de pesos, e determinar onde o resultado "cai":

```
lista = {
   30 => 'azul',
   10 => 'vermelha',
    5 => 'dourada',
   30 => 'preta',
   25 => 'cinza'
}

x = random( 1, 100 ) // aqui usamos 100, mas pode ser outra faixa de
                     // valores, só tomar o cuidado de notar que se
                     // passar da soma da lista o loop encerra

for each item in lista
   x = x - item.key
   if x <= 0
      return item.valor
   endif
next
```

Comment: O array de pesos parece uma das melhores ideias até então, visto que o código fica mais limpo e as probabilidades de cada item ficam claramente expostas. Podendo ser modificada futuramente caso seja necessário, possibilitando alterar as probabilidades e adicionar novos itens mais rapidamente.

Comment: Talvez dê até pra deixar mais enxuto dependendo da linguagem. Mas não se prenda só a essa solução, tem maneiras diversas de se fazer, qual é a melhor só depende do caso específico. Inclusive, se quiser deixar realmente portátil, precisa fazer a soma das chaves em vez de usar o número 100 literalmente. Assim você poderia ter simplesmente um 3 => a 1 => b se fosse uma proporção "três pra um". Aí não depende nem de porcentagem mais. Passa a funcionar em qualquer escala.

Answer (score 17):

Gere um número aleatório **x** : **x** ∈ [1,100].

- Se **x** ∈ [ 1,30]  - pegou uma bola azul
- se **x** ∈ [31,40]  - pegou uma bola vermelha
- se **x** ∈ [41,45]  - pegou uma bola dourada
- se **x** ∈ [46,75]  - pegou uma bola preta
- se **x** ∈ [76,100] - pegou uma bola cinza

**Exemplo de implementação em C#.**

A classe *BallsBag* simula a tiragem de bolas coloridas de um saco.
Simula dois comportamentos em função de a bola retirada voltar ou não ao saco.

Para cada conjunto de bolas inserido no saco(`InsertBallsByColor()`) é criado um `BallSet` que guarda a cor e um intervalo(`intervalLeft, intervalRight`).
Esse intervalo é calculado em função da quantidade de bolas já colocadas e a quantidade de bolas desse conjunto.

```
private int IntervalLeft() => _ballsInBag + 1;
private int IntervalRight(int count) => _ballsInBag + count;
```

Ele é usado para saber se, em função do valor aleatório gerado, foi tirada uma bola dessa cor.

```
public bool WasPicked(int pick)
{
    return pick >= _intervalLeft && pick <= _intervalRight;
}
```

A probabilidade de sair uma bola de uma determinada cor é a relação entre o número de bolas de dessa cor no saco e a quantidade total de bolas no saco.

```cs
public class BallsBag
{
    private static readonly int NUM_MAX_TIRAGENS = 5000;
    private readonly bool _extractedBallReturnsToBag;
    private int _ballsIn;
    private readonly IEnumerator<int>_randomGenerator ;
    private readonly HashSet<BallSet> _ballSetsInBag;
    private int _ballsExtracted;

    public BallsBag(int totalBalls, bool extractedBallReturnsToBag)
    {
        _extractedBallReturnsToBag = extractedBallReturnsToBag;
        TotalBalls = totalBalls;
        _ballSetsInBag = new HashSet<BallSet>();
        _randomGenerator = getRandomGenerator(TotalBalls, extractedBallReturnsToBag);
    }

    public int TotalBalls { get; }

    public int BallsInBag => _ballsIn - _ballsExtracted;

    public void InsertBallsByColor(string color, int count)
    {
        if (count <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count), $"{count} não é uma quantidade válida de bolas");
        }
        if (BallsExceedsMaximum(count))
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count), "Nº total de bolas excedido");
        }
        if(BagHaveThisBallColor(color))
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(color), "O saco já tem bolas dessa cor");
        }

        _ballSetsInBag.Add(new BallSet(color, IntervalLeft, IntervalRight(count)));
        _ballsIn = _ballsIn + count;
    }

    public string ExtractBall()
    {
        if (AllBallsNotInserted)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Ainda não colocou todas a bolas no saco");
        }
        if (_randomGenerator.MoveNext())
        {
            _ballsExtracted = _ballsExtracted + (_extractedBallReturnsToBag ? 0 : 1);
            var pickedBall = _randomGenerator.Current;
            return _ballSetsInBag.First(ball => ball.WasPicked(pickedBall)).Color;
        }
        throw new InvalidOperationException("O saco está vazio");
    }

    private bool BagHaveThisBallColor(string color) => _ballSetsInBag.Any(ball => ball.Color.Equals(color));
    private bool BallsExceedsMaximum(int count) => _ballsIn + count > TotalBalls;
    private int IntervalLeft => _ballsIn + 1;
    private int IntervalRight(int count) => _ballsIn + count;
    private bool AllBallsNotInserted => _ballsIn < TotalBalls;


    private IEnumerator<int> getRandomGenerator(int totalBalls, bool extractedBallReturnsToBag)
    {
        return extractedBallReturnsToBag ? RandomGenerator(1, totalBalls).GetEnumerator()
                                         : RandomGenerator(1, totalBalls).Distinct()
                                                                         .Take(totalBalls)
                                                                         .GetEnumerator();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<int> RandomGenerator(int minInclued, int maxInclued)
    {
        var rand = new Random();
        var i = 1;
        while (i <= NUM_MAX_TIRAGENS)
        {
            yield return rand.Next(minInclued, maxInclued + 1);
            i++;
        }
    }

    private class BallSet 
    {
        public string Color { get; }
        private readonly int _intervalLeft;
        private readonly int _intervalRight;

        public BallSet(string color, int intervalLeft, int intervalRight)
        {
            Color = color;
            _intervalLeft = intervalLeft;
            _intervalRight = intervalRight;
        }

        public bool WasPicked(int pick)
        {
            return pick >= _intervalLeft && pick <= _intervalRight;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var ballSetObj = obj as BallSet;
            return ballSetObj != null && Color.Equals(ballSetObj.Color);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Color.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Exemplo de utilização:

```cs
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var ballsBag = new BallsBag(20, extractedBallReturnsToBag: false);

    ballsBag.InsertBallsByColor("Azul",6);
    ballsBag.InsertBallsByColor("Vermelha", 2);
    ballsBag.InsertBallsByColor("Dourada", 1);
    ballsBag.InsertBallsByColor("Preta",6);
    ballsBag.InsertBallsByColor("Cinza", 5);

    Console.WriteLine($"Balls in bag {ballsBag.BallsInBag}");

    for (var i = 0; i < ballsBag.TotalBalls; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Tiragem {i+1} - {ballsBag.ExtractBall()} - Balls in bag {ballsBag.BallsInBag}");
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```