# Como gerar numeros aleatorios mas com algumas restriçoes em python?

Tags: python, random, números-aleatórios

```
import random
v=[1,7,15]
x=random.choice(v)
```

Como faço para gerar mais números "1" do que "15"? Em 10000 vezes, escolher 1 numero e no final:

o numero 1 deve ter saído aproximadamente 40%.

o numero 7 deve ter saído aproximadamente 30%.

o numero 15 deve ter saído aproximadamente 30%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A partir da versão 3.6, o pacote `random` possui a função [`choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) que permite você definir os pesos de cada valor dentro de uma população.

```
from random import choices

population = [1, 7, 15]
weights = [40, 30, 30]

samples = choices(population, weights, k=100)
```

O código acima irá gerar 100 valores aleatórios seguindo os pesos definidos.

---

Baseado em

[Sorteio aleatório, mas com diferentes probabilidades](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/147884/5878)

A forma mais fácil de implementar é gerar uma estrutura que já possua essas probabilidades. Como o número 1 deve possuir probabilidade igual a 40%, enquanto os números 7 e 15 devem possuir probabilidade igual a 30%, você pode gerar uma lista que possua 10 elementos ao todo, repetindo o número 1 quatro vezes e os números 7 e 15 três vezes cada.

```
v = [1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 7, 15, 15, 15]
```

Assim, ao fazer `random.choice(v)`, as probabilidades desejadas serão respeitadas.

Implementando de uma forma genética, e bastante simples, você pode definir uma função que gera esta lista conforme sua necessidade. Por exemplo:

```
from typing import Tuple, Any, List
from itertools import starmap, chain, repeat
from random import choice

def sample_space(*values: Tuple[Any, float]) -> List:
    if sum(value[1] for value in values) != 1.0:
        raise ValueError('Soma das probabilidades não é 1.0')
    while True:
        if all(probability.is_integer() for _, probability in values):
            break
        values = [(value, probability * 10) for value, probability in values]
    values = [(value, int(probability)) for value, probability in values]
    return list(chain(*starmap(lambda a, b: list(repeat(a, b)), values)))
```

A função `sample_space` irá gerar para você uma lista que define exatamente o espaço amostral que deseja, basta passar como parâmetro um conjunto de tuplas com valor e probabilidade desejada. Para os dados apresentados na pergunta, ficaria:

```
>>> space = sample_space((1, 0.4), (7, 0.3), (15, 0.3))
>>> print(space)
[1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 7, 15, 15, 15]
```

Se sortear 100 números deste espaço amostral e verificar quantas vezes se repetem (pode utilizar o [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) para isso), verá que as probabilidades tendem a ser seguidas:

```
>>> samples = [choice(space) for _ in range(100)]
>>> print(Counter(samples))
Counter({1: 40, 7: 32, 15: 28})
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/StarchyLoathsomeAttribute) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/MrsKS6)</sup>

Funcionará para quaisquer probabilidades, desde que a soma seja sempre 1.0. Por exemplo, para um espaço amostral que seja 99% `True` e 1% `False` ficaria:

```
>>> space = sample_space((True, 0.99), (False, 0.01))
```

Porém, isso geraria uma lista com 100 valores, sendo 99 `True` e 1 `False`; por isso, para esta solução, dada a simplicidade dela, tome cuidado para não gerar listas demasiadamente grandes e afetar a memória da aplicação. Quanto mais casas decimais possuir as probabilidades, mais elementos em memória serão necessários.

Comment: ia ficar maneiríssima com um exemplo do código para gerar a lista com as distribuições desejadas.

Comment: @jsbueno de fato, providenciarei.