# Aleatório dentro de um random

Tags: php

Galera, eu tenho esse código aqui:

```
<?php
// Define um array com alguns sites:
$site[] = 'google.com';
$site[] = 'facebook.com';


// Escolhe um valor aleatório (respeitando o total de sites)
$destino = rand(0, (count($site) - 1));

// Redireciona o usuario:
header("Location: " . $site[$destino]);
?>
```

Atualmente ele escolhe aleatoriamente entre os dois link e abre um deles. Mas queria uma alteração simples, e não sei como fazer exatamente pois não entendo muito disso. Eu queria que na segunda opção, tivesse duas opções. Mas como assim? Queria algo tipo assim?

```
<?php
// Define um array com alguns sites:
$site[] = 'google.com';
$site[] = 'youtube.com'  ouuu  'facebook.com';


// Escolhe um valor aleatório (respeitando o total de sites)
$destino = rand(0, (count($site) - 1));

// Redireciona o usuario:
header("Location: " . $site[$destino]);
?>
```

Sendo assim, um random dentro de um random. Alguém poderia me ajudar com isto?

Comment: E por que o `facebook.com` não poderia entrar como um terceiro item no array?

Comment: Por que eu queria apenas cerca de 25% dos acessos para este site. O google seria o redirecionamento principal, no caso cerca de 50% de chance. E dai esses outros 50% eu queria dividir entre os outros dois links, por isso não posso criar um terceiro array, pq se não ficaria cerca de 33% de chance de acesso em cada array

Comment: Então a pergunta deveria ser essa xD "Como fazer para sortear um valor considerando pesos diferentes para cada valor" ou algo assim.

Comment: Bastaria adicionar uma outra entrada de google ou fazer um array que coloca o peso de cada elemento e vê qual foi o índice baseado no range do rand (:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O que você quer é sortear um elemento da lista com pesos diferentes. Há uma explicação sobre isso na pergunta abaixo e não vale a pena replicar aqui:

- [Sorteio aleatório, mas com diferentes probabilidades](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/147884/5878)

Em PHP, uma possível implementação seria:

```
$urls = [
    'url A' => 50,
    'url B' => 25,
    'url C' => 25
];

$x = rand(0, 100);

foreach ($urls as $url => $probability) {
    $x -= $probability;

    if ($x <= 0) {
        echo $url;
        break;
    }
}
```

Onde a URL A tem 50% de chance de ser sorteada, URL B tem 25% e a URL C também 25% de chance de serem sorteadas. Você pode alterar `$urls` livremente, desde que a soma das probabilidades seja sempre 100, por questões óbvias.

Comment: Valeu, cara. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$sites = array("siteprincipal");
$site_ind = array("siteindependente1.com", "siteindependente2.com", "siteindependente3.com", "siteindependente4.com");
$sites[1] = $site_ind;
$destino = rand(0, count($sites)-1);
if(is_array($sites[$destino])){
    $destinoind = rand(0, count($sites[$destino])-1);
    header("Location:". $sites[$destino][$destinoind]);
}else{
    header("Location:".$sites[$destino]);
}
?>
```

Comment: Teria como me ajudar? Não entendo muito dessas coisas :/

Comment: Você vai usar somente três sites?

Comment: Serão 6. Ai queria tipo, 4 deles independentes, e dois dentro de uma unica array. Tipo assim:

`$site[] = 'site1.com';
$site[] = 'site2.com';
$site[] = 'site3.com';
$site[] = 'site4.com';
$site[] = 'site5.com'  ouuu  'site6.com';`

Comment: <?php
    $sites = array("siteprincipal");
    $site_ind = array("siteindependente1.com", "siteindependente2.com", "siteindependente3.com", "siteindependente4.com");
    $sites[1] = $site_ind;
    $destino = rand(0, count($sites)-1);
    if(is_array($sites[$destino])){
        $destinoind = rand(0, count($sites[$destino])-1);
        header("Location:". $sites[$destino][$destinoind]);
    }else{
        header("Location:".$sites[$destino]);
    }
    ?>

Comment: Vc só tem que quebrar as linhas pra ficar direitinho

Comment: E trocar as strings dentro dos arrays

Comment: Depois fala se deu certo

Comment: Eu segui o exemplo do outro cara ali acima. Mas muito obrigado pela força, cara.

Comment: Bruno, você pode **[edit]** sua resposta e colocar o código lá. É melhor porque fica mais organizado (toda a informação junta, assim as pessoas não precisam ficar "caçando" o código nos comentários), a além disso na resposta [é possível formatar o código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code), deixando-o bem mais legível do que nos comentários

Comment: Vlw, sou novo na plataforma kk